# Creating master playlist for HLS

Tags: php, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video.js, http-live-streaming

I am trying to implement adaptive stream using `HLS` I have video encoded in 4 different resolution with `.m3u8` extension

```
legend_240.m3u8
legend_360.m3u8
legend_480.m3u8
legend_720.m3u8
```

I encoded them using `FFMPEG` now I want to wrap them all in a master `HLS` playlist. How can I achieve this in an automated process?

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=17556000,RESOLUTION=428x240
legend_240.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=28556000,RESOLUTION=640x360
legend_360.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=56056000,RESOLUTION=854x480
legend_480.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=73056000,RESOLUTION=1280x720
legend_720.m3u8
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What error message did you get?

Comment: Use `ffprobe` to get the file information, if that's the question. For the bitrate you should already know the targeted value so just add the muxing overhead reported by `ffmpeg` when it finishes encoding.

Comment: @BPS i have tried creating it manually by myself as i read in an answer of a question here at stack overflow but now i wanted to automate that process

Comment: @aergistal thank you for your response can you please refer me to any example of doing so?

Comment: @Awaisfiaz [ffprobe wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips)

Comment: Thanks man! i was just wondering if i could achieve it using simple php scripting like files handling or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out using file handling in php.

```
        $myfile = fopen($this->raw_path."/".$this->file_name.".m3u8", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

        $txt = "#EXTM3U\n";

        fwrite($myfile, $txt);

        $txt = "#EXT-X-VERSION:3\n";

        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        // fclose($myfile);
        if($convertedRes['720']){

        $txt = "#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=73056000,RESOLUTION=1280x720\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        $txt = $this->file_name."/".$this->file_name."-720.m3u8\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);

        }
        if($convertedRes['480']){

        $txt = "#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=5605600,RESOLUTION=854x480\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        $txt = $this->file_name."/".$this->file_name."-480.m3u8\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);

        }

        if($convertedRes['360']){

        $txt = "#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2855600,RESOLUTION=640x360\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        $txt = $this->file_name."/".$this->file_name."-360.m3u8\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);

        }

        if($convertedRes['240']){


        $txt = "#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1755600,RESOLUTION=428x240\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        $txt = $this->file_name."/".$this->file_name."-240.m3u8\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);


        }


fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: By using PHP to generate master, it works on smartphone? I've done a similar thing, but cant reproduce live streaming on smartphone :/